# form_remote_tag to upload a Paperclip file attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I am having a rails form which has one field of image upload, like:

```
<% form_for @c, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field(:b, :size=>63, :class=>"fontsize13") %>
   <%= image_tag @c.b.url(:thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

On saving this form, the action is

```
def update
  @c = C.find(params[:id])
  if params[:c]
    @c.update_attributes(params[:c])
    if @c.save
               redirect_to :action => "index"
    else
      flash[:error] = @c.errors.full_messages.join('<br />')
    end
  end
end
```

This will upload the image and loads the same page again to show the image uploaded in the preview and in the layout logo too.

I am trying to show the image on save by ajax instead of page refreshing again.

I have tried with form_remote_tag by

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => {:controller => "c",:action => "update"}, :html => {:multipart => true } do |f| -%>
  <%= f.file_field :b%>
<% end %>
```

But this shows me error as `Undefined method file_field for nil`

Please give suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this blog post http://railsblaster.wordpress.com/2007/09/20/ajax-forms-and-file-uploading-in-rails/

form_remote_tag and file_field doesn't marry each other for some security reasons. The blog post will give you some alternate options instead.

Comment: http://justinvadakkan.blogspot.com/2010/12/file-upload-without-reload-page.html fixed my issue